# find: '/sys/kernel/slab': Input/output error

Tags: linux, find, slab

When i excuted the find command on the terminal of the Nethunter phone, i got some error:
The find command:

```
find / -name hid-keyboard
```

The error i got:

```
find: '/sys/kernel/slab': Input/output error
```

Additional:

devices is: Xiaomi Mi6 (sagit)

os is : Lineaged OS 19.1 (Android12)

nethunter version: 2022.3(2022030100)